# Extra allocs valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

Here is my valgrind output

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes new
==14028== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14028== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14028== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14028== Command: new
==14028==
allocated
deleted
==14028==
==14028== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14028==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==14028==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,754 bytes allocated
==14028==
==14028== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==14028==    at 0x4C29C23: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==14028==    by 0x4EBF18F: pool (eh_alloc.cc:117)
==14028==    by 0x4EBF18F: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (eh_alloc.cc:244)
==14028==    by 0x4EBF18F: _GLOBAL__sub_I_eh_alloc.cc (eh_alloc.cc:307)
==14028==    by 0x400FB02: _dl_init (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==14028==    by 0x4001069: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==14028==
==14028== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14028==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14028==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14028==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14028==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==14028==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14028==
==14028== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14028== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see the extra alloc seems to be from some source I can't identify, valgrind lists it as ???. Is this just some weird allocation behind the scenes? Should I worry about it?

Comment: Yes.  Valgrind is smarter than you are.  `in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
 total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,754 bytes allocated`  Not good.  Two allocations and one free.

Comment: This is an allocation made by the dynamic linker; this is ok, you do not need to worry about that.

Comment: Note, `valgrind` releases prior to 3.13 provided better exclusion files that would properly account for the `72,404` base allocation. There have been several bug reports filed, but given the differences between 3.12 and 3.13, the folks at valgrind.org have not been willing to fix this issue (for both C and C++).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin valgrind release is now 3.14, and if ever such allocation reports are appearing (typically due to changes in glibc/ld/...), then valgrind and/or glibc/ld/... cooperate to avoid these reports. See a.o. the option --run-cxx-freeres and bug 348978. You might need a newer valgrind and/or newer glibc/ld/... to have all this fixed. If ever you still have a problem, please report or update a bug on valgrind bugzilla, and we will happily fix it, when time permits :). For sure, the objective is to have clean output for clean programs.

Comment: @phd sure, I'll refile and amend, but I've previously opened 2 bug reports about this issues and was basically given a WONTFIX [bug 1 with valgrind (kde.org bugzilla)](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392855), and [bug 2 with openSuSE re: Leap 15](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1092054)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  some more info was requested for valgrind kde bugzilla 392855, as the behaviour looks normal. It looks like you are expecting that valgrind 'hides' the allocations in printf library function, but why would this function be handled specially compared to all other zillions of libraries that allocate some memory : for all these functions, that memory must better be reported (same feedback on both the kde valgrind bug and on the openSuSE bug).

Comment: @phd I updated to valgrind.org bug report. We also have this C++ example here (and every other C or C++ report of allocated memory not totaling what the user requested since 3.13 was released.) [valgrind.org buf - comment 10](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392855#c9) Now we will see if the bug gets worked, or if it is just given lip-service but never fixed. I sure hope it is fixed, it dramatically reduces the educational value of valgrind for new users (now generating questions on programming site "where do the extra allocations come from?") The proof is in the pudding.

Answer (score 1):

This allocation/'still reachable' memory report is normal, and has been reported on valgrind bugzilla (and fixed) : see a.o. bugs https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345307 and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=348978.

You might need to upgrade to a newer valgrind and/or newer ld/glibc/... to have all that fixed.

If you cannot upgrade yet, in the meantime, you can use a suppression file.

Run valgrind + your program with the valgrind option --gen-suppressions=yes (or =all) to provide the needed suppression entry.